# Proof for nullset that does not consist of countable points.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

With the help I got in an earlier post,  ([Proving that $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$ is a null subset of $\mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3422615/proving-that-mathbb-q-cap-0-1-is-a-null-subset-of-mathbb-r/3422618#3422618)), I figured out the proof that every countable set is a null set w.r.t. Lebesgue-measure and was able to apply it to examples from different dimensions. But now at this example:   $$A =\Bigl\{\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\\frac{1}{x}\\\end{array}\right)|x \in [1,2]\Bigr\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$$, 
I'm stuck again since there is no way to put decreasing intervals around every point since there is infinitely many. So how would I provide a proof with the definition being:

$A \subset\mathbb Q$ is called a null set, if $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there exists a countable number of cuboids $\{Q_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ with volume $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty} \operatorname{vol}(Q_k) < \epsilon $ with $A \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} Q_k $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uniform continuous function $\varphi(x)=1/x$ on $[1,2]$ is such that $A=\{(x,\varphi(x)):x\in[1,2]\}$. Given $\epsilon>0$, there is an $n_{0}$ such that $|x-y|<1/n_{0}$ implies $|\varphi(x)-\varphi(y)|<\epsilon$ for all $x,y\in[1,2]$. Then 
\begin{align*}
A\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\left(I_{i}\times\left[\min_{I_{i}}f,\max_{I_{i}}f\right]\right),
\end{align*}
and hence $|A|\leq\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\max_{I_{i}}f-\min_{I_{i}}f)|I_{i}|$, where $I_{i}=[1+(i-1)/n_{0},1+i/n_{0}]$, and hence $|A|<\epsilon\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}|I_{i}|=\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks. Is $i$ the imaginary unit?

Comment: No, the running variable in the sum.

Comment: Oh, I was too quick because I saw a different proof using complex numbers, sorry.

Comment: Could you also explain where $\min_{I_{i}}f $ and $\max_{I_{i}}f$ are coming from?

Comment: $f$ is continuous on the compact interval $I_{i}$ and hence the $\max,\min$ exist.